# Image doesn't appear in custom view renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've this cusom view in shared project:

```
public class CustomAdView : View
{

}
```

then I add it in the main page:

```
var adView = new CustomAdView();
Grid.SetRowSpan(adView, 4);
_mainGrid.Children.Add(adView);
// here if I add an Image instead, it shows without problem.
```

Then in the android project, I've a custom renderer for that `CustomAdView` like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomAdView), typeof(CustomAdViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomAdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomAdView, Android.Views.View>
    {
        public CustomAdViewRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomAdView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null)
                SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
        }

        // ...

        private Android.Views.View CreateAdView()
        {
            try
            {
                var url = RequestImageUrlFromServer();

                var imageView = new ImageView(Context);
                imageView.Click += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
                };
                imageView.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                imageView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FillParent, LayoutParams.FillParent);

                return imageView;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CreateAdView()` returns `imageView` correctly. If I click on the screen, it responds to click event and opens the browser, but the problem is that it doesn't show the image!

I guess I set `ImageView` source incorrectly. Image url is something like this:

```
https://addeals.s3.amazonaws.com/campaigns/pub8/testing/768x1024_hangman_test.jpg
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code

```
var iamgeview = new ImageView(Context);
URL url = new URL("xxx");
Bitmap pngBP = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenStream());
iamgeview.SetImageBitmap(pngBP);
```